# GIMP (GTK): Jump to corner / Move viewport to corner

Tags: gimp

I manually edit lot of images in GIMP: scrolling to corners, sometimes making small changes, but always "circling" more than few times. (Top-left, top-right, bottom-right, bottom-left... top-left, top-right, bottom-right, bottom-left... and again... and again, etc.)

Because I'm spending more time navigating than making changes, I'd like to be able to quick-jump to corner. ("Jump to top-left", "Jump to top-right", "Jump to bottom-right" and "Jump to bottom-left".)

More precisely, to move the corner of the "viewport" to the corner of the document:

[image: Jump to corner]

1 - I did try Navigation dock (and "Navigate the image display" button and preview window), but for me a) it isn't very "quick" and precise jump, and b) if I navigate to the corner, then it puts the corner of the document in center:

[image: Navigation dock]

I think that is "canvas padding", but I don't know how to disable it:

[image: GIMP canvas padding settings]

2 - I tried to find/create "jump to corner" `scm` script, but (if my understanding is correct) GIMP script can't control GIMP user interface.

3 - I also made few tests with `xdotool` and `xbindkeys` (Debian bullseye/sid, BTW.), but nothing happens in GIMP:

```
# this scrolls up/down in xterm when I press control+shift+alt+ h/l

# wheel up
"xdotool click 4" 
  control+shift+alt + h

# wheel down
"xdotool click 5" 
  control+shift+alt + l
```

Thanks for any suggestion you may have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, Ctrl-cursor scrolls to the end of the scrolling range, so, for instance:

- Ctrl-(CursUp,CursLeft) puts you in the top left corner
- Ctrl-(CursUp,CursRight,CursDown,CurlLeft,CursUp) cycles you through the 4 corners in clockwise order.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I want.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a method that doesn't involve any coding.

1. Open the image and do *View > New View* three times, to open the same image file in 4 tabs.
2. Zoom and navigate to the location you want in each tab.
3. Click on the tabs along the top to work on the part of the image you want.
4. You can also use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>PgUp</kbd> or <kbd>PgDn</kbd> to cycle through the open tabs.

[image]

Comment: This is what I call _creative thinking_. I'll definitely keep this method in mind. Thanks!